# Capturing bitmap representation of touchscreen

Tags: mobile, signal-processing, tablet, touchscreen, imaging

I am interested to take a "screenshot" of entire screen from touch-screen perspective.  In other words, I am interested to save an image representation that shows what touchscreen is seeing at a particular moment.  For example, if at the moment of recording, there are three fingers on the screen, then the image would show three blobs, assuming I choose white as no touch detection and black as touch.  Another example, if I place a hand on the screen, image would show something like a palm print.

Is this achievable with current mainstream iPhone/Android/tablet devices?
If achievable, what sensitivity/granularity can I get?  For example, will it be a binarized representation, or can I represent edges via 256-level grey shades?  How sensitive is the touchscreen, i.e. what is the smallest object size that can be detected, such as ball-pen-size stylus?

I can find surprisingly little information on this subject.  If you know some resource, please let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because in my company we are designing touch screen sensors, I got used with such images. I can show you 2 pictures, that are showing what you were looking for:

- In putting my fingers on the touch screen
  [image: fingers on the touch screen]
- In putting my palm plus the fingers
  [image: fingers and palm on the touch screen]

In this case the touch screen has 64 columns and 36 rows.

Unfortunately, these data are available only at a R&D stage, so you can't have access to it on the final commercial product.
Maybe other vendors allow their customer to see these data (we call it raw data), but we don't for confidentiality reasons.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was referring to.  I was looking for the same on a) any mobile device (iPhone, Android) and b) hopefully with finer resolution.  I am trying to dig deep into those libraries.  In your lab setup, you have multiple grey levels, which is great to represent density or weight of the touch at every pixel.

Comment: In reality we are using a jet color map instead of a grey level, it's more fancy, and it allows to make the difference between no data (black), and 0 (blue).